# Получение в JS большого массива данных с сервера

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, передача-данных

Дорогие форумчане.
Возникла проблема.
Есть сервер с **php**, есть данные с этого сервера, около 1.200.000 строк, суммарно +- 10мб чистого текста, который  пробовал либо считывать с MySql и ро строкам запихивать в массив либо считывать по строком с текстового файла и так же сувать в массив ( уже ужал как мог). Все это необходимо для отрисовки на canvas картинки, которая может меняться. ( Просто отрисовать картинку drawimage не выйдет ). В строчке значения цветов в hex-кодировке под каждый пиксель по порядку.

**Задача** как то передать с сервера эти данные в Js, для корректной отрисовки страницы.

Я запихиваю каждую строчку как ячейку массива и отправляю этот массив Ajax ( XML ) запросом. Ну и на стороне пользователя все это дело обрабатывается как нужно. Проблема в том, что таким образом дольше всего времени занимает скачивание такого большого массива. Это, конечно напрямую зависит от скорости интернета пользователя, но со средним 3g это прям секунд 20.

Долго думал, много где рылся, в гугле лазил - все безуспешно. Допускаю, что чего то не знаю, или туплю, но очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135843/discussion-on-question-by-v---js-----).

Comment: Ну если уж так необходимо передавать на клиента большой объем данных, то почему бы не генерировать на сервере уже скрипт с содержанием этих же данных с использованием кэширования? Это должно значительно снизить нагруску на сервере и увеличит скоростт обработки на стороне клиента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и предложили участники форума, возпользовался библиотекой GD для php,чтобы обрабатывать и данные еще на сервере и составлять картинку из них, а затем отправлять уже готовую картинку.